# "purposed" imbalanced data and class_weight in keras

Tags: keras

I have 4 classes, namely **a**, **b**, **c**, **d**. With training data as follows (approx):

**a**: 1500
**b**: 500
**c**: 500
**d**: 500

So class **a** has a sample count 3 times to **b**, **c** and **d**

In real case scenario, the probability of emergence of **a** could be much higher than **b**,**c**,**d**. And if the model has difficulty in making decisions, I also want it to select **a**.

In this case, in the **fit_generator** function of keras, do I need to specify the **class_weight** parameter ?

Many thanks !

Comment: So, you want the model to be biased towards A ? if it isnt explicitly B,C,D ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan yes, that's correct

Comment: how is the prediction now ? without class weights ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan In my case, class c and d have stronger features in shape, and I think that it makes the model show advantages for c and d over a. So the result shows that many class a samples are classified as c or d. And what I want is that the model could show a  preference for class a.

Comment: how is the variability or correlation for features with respect to classes ? like are there distinguishable features for class a ? or its almost similar to class c and d ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnanv Suppose this case: a(oval), b(circle), c(triangle), d(rectangle). Since respect to b,c,d, the class a (oval shape) is not so distinguishable, so the model tends to classify class a as b, c or d (considering that a is not perfect oval)

Comment: okay. then the increased data points didnt make a difference. You can try adding class weights with a having more weight then

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Thanks. But if I have more data points in class a, shouldn't I expect an elevated weight for class a in loss calculation ?

Comment: yes.. since its images use dice loss and give more weights to other classes. look for weighted dice loss.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Thank you again. I am using the cross_entropy loss to compile the model using model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"]). The labels are hot-encoded. I haven't heard of dice loss before you mentioned above. After googling a bit, I found that it is actually not the loss function I was using.

Comment: you can't use dice.. i am sorry.  yours is a classification problem. my bad